# WCF Performance issue: requests are stopped getting processed

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, msmq

I have been experiencing the issue in WCF service. It stops  processing requests after some time. We have sceduled automatic recycling at regular intervals (nearly 4 times an hour) to fix it temporary.
I have taken the memory dumps from the server and it seems that 1 thread ( that actually does logging using enterprise library) is getting locked and other are waiting for it but i am a little confused.

I used Windbg tool to get the performance statistics:-
!threads give me below data :-

```
74   60 202c 000000000f1fce10  3029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000252a6b0 1     MTA (Threadpool Worker) System.Messaging.MessageQueueException 00000003ffc67350
```

The !syncblk gives me below :-

[Syncblk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiOnk.jpg)

Logging component is asynchronous and sends the message to MSMQ. one thread gets locked when external system exception comes , it displays that around 1000 threads waiting( Monitorthread in syncbklk) and all those are threads waiting to enter the logging.
What i do not understand is why 1 thread getting locked is denying other threads because MSMQ is not blocked as other applivations use the same MSMQ and working fine.
Secondly, the logging component just sends the message to MSMQ , can we consider it a potential blockage to actual application.
The asynchronous code used in logging is :-

```
enter code here action = new Action<LogEntry>(Logger.Write);
            IAsyncResult iAr = action.BeginInvoke(entry, CallbackHandler, action);action.EndInvoke(iar);
```

Kindly suggest on above problem statement.
[Exception details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0oOe.jpg)

---

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the windbg tool you are getting the System.Messaging.MessageQueueException exception on thread 74. you can get the exception message using the !dso command in windbg tool like "Insufficient resources (something like that).

As shown in the exception image , your thread is getting blocked because unless it does not perform its action of sending the data to MSMQ it will not get release and other threads will also get stuck because of that thread.

for more information you can follow the below link.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2006/09/18/insufficient-resources-run-away-run-away/